# Being chair in easychair, are bids for my own paper visible to me?

Tags: easychair

I'm the chair of a conference managed by easychair. I have, myself, submitted a paper, and, of course, marked it as having a conflict.

I'm currently monitoring the bids of program committee members, and don't see my paper selected by anyone.

My question is: *am I not seeing it because nobody has selected it? or because I have a conflict with it and therefore it remains invisible to me?*

Both of these two possible explanations make sense: (a) My paper is not interesting enough. (b) I'm not supposed to know who has reviewed my paper, so logically I should not know either who is volunteering to review it.

But then again, in the eventuality of (b) and since I'm the one assigning papers for review, how can I assign my paper when I don't see it??

[It would be so much easier to be able to ask this question to easychair, but they will *not answer any technical questions* as long as you have a free account…]

Answer (score 1):

Having asked a friend to check it appeared that the second explanation is true: bids on my own paper are hidden from me. Remains to question about how to assign it to a reviewer…

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making another PC member a chair?  Another chair might be able to assign your paper to reviewers.

By chance, I wonder if you were able to see your paper if you made someone else a chair and signed in through them.  You have the ability to sign in as another PC member because you are the first chair.  I wouldn't recommend it for your current situation because it would be unethical, but in a test situation, it would be ok.  If you are then able to see your paper and the reviewers, then EasyChair should be notified to correct this workaround.